# Why does loop in other loop woks wierd?

Tags: python, for-loop

When i make loop in other loop it gives me duplicated value

```
a = []
i = 0
while True:
  i += 0.1
  i = round(i,1)
  a.append(i)
  if i == 13:
    break
  
maybe_corr_nums1 = []
maybe_corr_nums2 = []
for i in a:
  for j in a:
    num = i + j
    num = round(num,1)
    if num == 8:
      maybe_corr_nums1.append(i)
      maybe_corr_nums2.append(j)
print(maybe_corr_nums2)    

      
maybe_corr_nums3 = []
corr_nums1 = []
for i in a:
  for j in maybe_corr_nums1:
    num = i + j
    num = round(num)
    if num == 13:
      maybe_corr_nums3.append(i)
      corr_nums1.append(j)
print(maybe_corr_nums3)
```

First print gives me right result, but second gives me list with duplicated numbers

Comment: Why wouldn't it give you duplicates?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

> The error seems to be in `num = round(num)` of the second loop which explained why you had the repetition so I changed it to `num = round(num,1)` as it is supposed to do the same as above which seems to work but starts at 5 :(.
> **Is it supposed to start from 0 and go to 13?**

```
a = []
i = 0
while True:
  i += 0.1
  i = round(i,1)
  a.append(i)
  if i == 13:
    break
  
maybe_corr_nums1 = []
maybe_corr_nums2 = []
for i in a:
  for j in a:
    num = i + j
    num = round(num,1)
    if num == 8:
      maybe_corr_nums1.append(i)
      maybe_corr_nums2.append(j)
print(maybe_corr_nums2)    

      
maybe_corr_nums3 = []
corr_nums1 = []
for i in a:
  for j in maybe_corr_nums1:
    num = i + j

    num = round(num,1) ## added ,1 like it is in the first one 
    if num == 13:
      maybe_corr_nums3.append(i)
      corr_nums1.append(j)

print(maybe_corr_nums3)
```

Comment: is it meant to start from 0 and go to 13?

Comment: Please when answering, at least explain what was the problem and what you changed to fix it. Just saw it as a comment in the middile of the code, make it easier to see, as text, at first